# Получить уникальное значение по колонке подтаблицы. Запрос на SQL или на JPQL

Tags: sql

Таблица А:

```
--------------------
id | photo  | id_b |
--------------------
 1 | Лондон | 1    |
--------------------
 2 | Париж  | 1    |
--------------------
 3 | цветок | 1    |
--------------------
 4 | авто   | 2    |
--------------------
 5 | кружка | 2    |
--------------------
```

Таблица B (есть подтаблицой А):

```
--------------
id_b | user  |
--------------
1    | Петр  |
--------------
2    | Иван  |
--------------
```

ВОПРОС:
Как получить список элементов таблицы А, содержащий такие элементы:

```
1 / Лондон / 1
4 / авто / 2
```

То есть по одному фото от user_а.

Подскажите пожалуйста как написать запрос на sql, а лучше на jpql для Hibernate для аннотации @Query в Spring

Comment: Решение для MySQL зависит от версии MySQL. Для JPQL, не знающего ни про СТЕ, ни про оконные функции - однозначно подзапрос.

Comment: Тут отлично подойдут оконные функции, если они имеются в вашей СУБД. В противном случае только подзапросом.

Answer (score 0):

**Для SQL:**
SELECT DISTINCT a.* FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON a.id_b = b.id_b GROUP BY a.id_b

**Для SQL в месте с java (interface JpaRepository)/Hibernate/spring:**
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT DISTINCT a.* FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON a.id_b = b.id_b GROUP BY a.id_b")

Comment: Ну-ну... ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY будет счастлив объяснить Вам всю глубину Вашего заблуждения...